# How to test my API apps before hosting in AZURE

Tags: azure-api-apps

I have written a simple API using Visual studio by using Azure API template. Wanted to test it using Swagger before hosting in AZURE.

Could anyone please let me know the steps ?

Thanking you in advance

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your questions correctly, you could un-comment few lines from SwaggerConfig.cs file to activate Swagger for your API application. To do this, in your solution look for the file 'SwaggerConfig.cs'

From VS Solution' >> App_Start and then find SwaggerConfig.cs

Find EnableSwaggerUi and remove comments for below line of code

```
        /*
            })
        .EnableSwaggerUi(c =>
            {
        */
```

Also, take a look at the approach outlined here: -https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-rest-api

Else, kindly provide more details on your requirement to better assist you.

Comment: Hi Ajay, thanks for your comments. i have enabled SwaggerUi and then try to access Swagger like this "http://localhost:58454/swagger/" Or "http://localhost/swagger" but it is throwing an error "This site can’t be reached"

Comment: Glad to know that it is working fine. Thanks for the update.